# Sum of two Fox H-functions

Tags: summation, special-functions, complex-integration

I want to add up the following two Fox H-functions
$$
H_{1,2}^{\,1,1} \!\left[ -\lambda^2 \left|x\right|^{2\alpha^\prime}
\left| 
\begin{matrix}
( 0 , 1 ) \\
( 0 , 1 ) & ( 0 , 2\alpha^\prime ) 
\end{matrix} 
\right. \right]
+ i\times
H_{1,2}^{\,1,1} \!\left[ -\lambda^2 \left|x\right|^{2\alpha^\prime}
\left| 
\begin{matrix}
( \frac{1}{2} , 1 ) \\
( \frac{1}{2} , 1 ) & ( 0 , 2\alpha^\prime ) 
\end{matrix} 
\right. \right]
$$

where $\lambda$ and $\alpha^\prime$ are real numbers and

$$
H_{p,q}^{\,m,n} \!\left[ z \left| \begin{matrix}
( a_1 , A_1 ) & ( a_2 , A_2 ) & \ldots & ( a_p , A_p ) \\
( b_1 , B_1 ) & ( b_2 , B_2 ) & \ldots & ( b_q , B_q ) \end{matrix} \right. \right]
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L 
\frac
{(\prod_{j=1}^m\Gamma(b_j+B_js))(\prod_{j=1}^n\Gamma(1-a_j-A_js))}
{(\prod_{j=m+1}^q\Gamma(1-b_j-B_js))(\prod_{j=n+1}^p\Gamma(a_j+A_js))}
z^{-s} \, ds
$$

Is it possible to convert the above summation to just one Fox H-function?

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$H = H_{1, 2}^{1, 1} {\left(-z \middle|
  {(0, 1) \atop (0, 1), (0, \alpha)} \right)} +
 i H_{1, 2}^{1, 1} {\left(-z \middle|
  {(\frac 1 2, 1) \atop (\frac 1 2, 1), (0, \alpha)} \right)} = \\
\frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_{\mathcal L}
 \frac
  {\Gamma(1 + y) \Gamma(-y) + i \Gamma(\frac 1 2 + y) \Gamma(\frac 1 2 - y)}
  {\Gamma(1 + \alpha y)} (-z)^y dy = \\
-\frac 1 {2 \pi i} \frac 1 \pi \int_{\mathcal L}
 \frac
  {\Gamma(y) \Gamma(1 - y) \Gamma(\frac 1 2 + y) \Gamma(\frac 1 2 - y)}
  {\Gamma(1 + \alpha y)} e^{-i \pi y} (-z)^y dy.$$
For $z > 0$, $e^{-i \pi y} (-z)^y = z^y$. Therefore
$$H = -\frac 1 \pi H_{2, 3}^{2, 2} {\left(z \middle|
 {(1, 1), (\frac 1 2, 1) \atop (1, 1), (\frac 1 2, 1), (0, \alpha)} \right)}.$$

Comment: Could you please tell me how you got the third line?

Comment: Use $\Gamma(y) \Gamma(1 - y) = \pi \csc \pi y$ to reduce the integrands to elementary functions (divided by $\Gamma(1 + \alpha y)$).